# Understanding pages in Laravel when coming from Drupal?

Tags: laravel, drupal-8

I am trying to understand what is the best way to do different types of pages in Laravel.

In Drupal, you create a control which generates form elements to create a page. 
In Laravel, I see you usually create controllers when you want get/set/view actions. So, if I was making a site a bout Cars, I would create a CarsController and manage the Cars from there.

But right now, I just want a page that grabs data from the database and displays it on the home page. It could even be done as the equivelant of "blocks" in Drupal. So that I can re-use them.

What is the best way to do this in Laravel?

I can create home.blade.php and put the php in there. But I can't imagine it being correct to do a database call in a template? It would make sense that the db calls happen in a controller and then the result is somehow passed to the template.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

I see you can do this:

```
Route::get('greeting', function () {
    return view('welcome', ['name' => 'Samantha']);
});
```

So, technically I could do the DB calls right there. Is that the best place to do it? It feels like I should be using a controller from here somehow?

Comment: best way to start is laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8 and check out some basic laravel tutorials.

Comment: A lot of folks use Eloquent to pull data (for example, Cars) from their database.  The do this in the controller and then call the blade, which renders the database content.  So, for each controller function and route, you'll have to call both "Get my data" (via Eloquent or however you like) and "display my data".